# How i can pass array from Node js to Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug, sequelize.js

I'm locked up a bit on this issue.
I can not pass my array from Nodejs to Angularjs to make a ng-repeat.
I take the data with sequelize:

```
models.Event
        .findAll({attributes: [[sequelize.literal('DISTINCT incoming '), 'incoming']]})
        .then(function(items){
            var result = [];
            items.forEach(function (item) {
                result.push(item.dataValues.incoming)
            });
```

and in my jade file:

```
 div(layout='row', layout-align='space-between center')
                        md-input-container(flex)
                            label(for='buyerIncoming') Iscrizione agli Incoming
                            md-select(ng-model='buyer.incoming', name='buyerIncoming', id='buyerIncoming')
                                md-option(ng-repeat='incoming in dataList') {{ incoming }}
```

But I do not receive anything. If I insert a console.log in the jade file I recive [1, 2]

Where am I wrong?

Comment: it is not visible dow you push the data to the view (dataList) also... the way you can do this i a bit ugly way. I suggest to use an API call instead of rendering the view on server. Take a look at ng-init for this purpose

Comment: You can use json to store your data and pass it on to angular.